# I am unable to dock a ComboBox in a TableLayoutPanel cell

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, tablelayoutpanel

Please see the image below: I want to dock a **ComboxBox** control in a cell of my TableLayoutPanel.

The ComboBox `Dock` property is set to **Fill** and the `Anchor` property to **top, bottom, left and right**.

[image: Properties shown and document outline also shown with form]

Comment: The ComboBox height is based on the Font height, no mater how you dock it. Btw, when you dock a Control, the anchors you set become irrelevant. Maybe you want to auto-size the TableLayoutPanel's Cells to their content instead?

Comment: Sir thanks for the answer. no i just want to dock the combox box to my table cell

Answer (score 4):

**TL; DR**

It's expected  behavior, for `ComboBox` setting `Dock` to `Fill` doesn't fill the container. it's Height is calculated based on its `Font` height or for an owner-draw ComboBox based on its `ItemHeight`.

If it's really necessary for you to change the behavior, you can hack the behavior by overriding its `SetBoundsCore` method.

---

**Long Answer - A ComboBox which supports Dock = Fill**

The height of `ComboBox` is controlled based on the following rules:

- If the control's [`DrawMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is Normal, then the height will be based on Font.Height
- If the control's [`DrawMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) is OwnerDraw then the height will be based on the [ItemHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.itemheight?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

So it doesn't support Docking-Fill.

But you can hack the behavior; You can derive from `ComboBox` and change the behavior by overriding [`SetBoundsCore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setboundscore?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }
    protected override void SetBoundsCore(
        int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
    {
        base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
        if (Dock == DockStyle.Fill ||
            Dock == DockStyle.Left ||
            Dock == DockStyle.Right)
        {
            var d = SystemInformation.FixedFrameBorderSize.Height;
            ItemHeight = height - 2 * d;
        }
        else
        {
            ItemHeight = FontHeight + 2;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        var text = e.Index >= 0 ? GetItemText(e.Index) : string.Empty;
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, e.Font, e.Bounds, e.ForeColor,
            TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
    }
}
```

And as result:

[image]

Comment: Does the post answers your question?

Comment: How to dock textbox to fill area like above combo box? thanks

Comment: @Ihdina Just set Multiline = true, and then Dock = Fill.

Comment: Thanks brother, it works, but the text is not centered from the vertical, so the text looks like it's hanging on top (top docking). How to make text in middle-left when height is changed?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already you cannot change the height of combobox and textbox using anchor or dock property. You can change the font size in Font property. the default is 8.25pt.

[Like Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rig9.png)